# How to use KalturaMediaFilter for statusIn?

Tags: java, kaltura

I am using kaltura java API in my project.
I want to list down all deleted videos.
So I am using following filter:

```
KalturaMediaEntryFilter entryFilter = new KalturaMediaEntryFilter();
entryFilter.statusEqual = KalturaEntryStatus.DELETED;
```

Now i want to list all videos with status READY and DELETED
I know there is filter named "statusIn" but i don't know how to use that filter.
I tried to use below combinations, but giving me an error:

```
entryFilter.statusIn = "KalturaEntryStatus.READY,KalturaEntryStatus.DELETED";
entryFilter.statusIn = "READY,DELETED";
entryFilter.statusIn = "ready,deleted";
```

Above combination does not workout.
Please correct me or suggest how to use that filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:
entryFilter.statusIn = "2,3";

See the reference of the Kaltura entry status enum:
http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/?object=KalturaEntryStatus

Comment: Will this give me both READY as well as DELETED records ?

Comment: What is default paging size of KalturaFilterPager ?

Comment: The default page size is 30

Comment: Of course the best way to do this is just entryFilter.statusIn = KalturaEntryStatus.READY + ", " + KalturaEntryStatus.DELETED; or something similar

Comment: Thanks geek for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the way to achieve this:

```
mediaFilter.statusIn = "" + KalturaEntryStatus.READY.hashCode + "," + KalturaEntryStatus.DELETED.hashCode;
```